# Swap/Replace makers on google map api with javascript, phonegape

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

I'm using phonegape and google map api.

In main loop i want to swap the old markers table for the others. This code work, but it doesn't erase old markers - It save the old and add the new.

```
if(markers){

      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var draftMarker = markers[i];
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(draftMarker[1], draftMarker[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: draftMarker[0],
                           });
        }
    }
    else{
    }
```

My markers table looks like

Old

```
 [["Opera Nova","53.124392","17.997760"],["Ratusz","53.122464","17.999005"], ["Domek","53.1257889","18.0668405"]]
```

New

```
[["Bankomat BZ WBK","53.1243946","18.001958"],["Bankomat BZ WBK","53.1257889","18.0668405"]]
```

I generates Markers table with Ajax & JSON. I get new table when i push button.

When i tried this (code bellow) - there aren't any markers on the map.

```
 if(markers){
for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
    marker[i].setMap(null);
 }

          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var draftMarker = markers[i];
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(draftMarker[1], draftMarker[2]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: draftMarker[0],
                               });
            }
        }
        else{
        }
```

Comment: `marker` is a `google.maps.Marker` , not an array.

Comment: create an array where you store the markers and iterate over the markers in  this array to set the map to null